# Updating a binary field taking a file from filesystem without using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, try-catch, openrowset

**The Scenario**

I have a table (let's call it `myTable`) in Sql Server 2005 with some columns, including a `varbinary(max)` field:

- **REPORT_ID** `int` *(primary key)*
- **REPORT_FILE**   `varbinary(max)`
- ...

I often need to update the files contained inside the `varbinary(max)` column via TSQL scripts reading a file from the filesystem. These scripts are executed in Sql Server Management Studio.

I wrote the following script to update the binary value using `OPENROWSET`:

```
begin try
    begin tran
    update myOtherTable set field1 = 'value1'
    --other instructions
    --...

    UPDATE myTable 
    SET [REPORT_FILE] = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\filename.ext', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T)
    WHERE REPORT_ID = ...
end try

begin catch
    if @@TRANCOUNT > 0 begin
        rollback tran
        --other instructions for error handling
        --...
    end
end catch

if @@TRANCOUNT > 0  begin
    commit tran
end
```

**The Problem**

I want to handle the scenario where the file is missing or the filename is wrong; the desired behavior is:

- `rollback` if an error occurs
- `commit` if everything worked

If the input file is missing the above script generates an error, but the `CATCH` block fails to capture the exception, so the transaction and the update to `myOtherTable` remain pending because the `COMMIT` instruction isn't executed. As a result I have to rollback the transaction manually.

**My solution**

The only way I have found to capture the error in the `CATCH` block is using dynamic TSQL, so my actual script is:

```
declare @dSQL nvarchar(max)

begin try
    begin tran
        update myOtherTable set field1 = 'value1'
        --other instructions 
        --...
        set @dSQL = '
            UPDATE myTable 
            SET [REPORT_FILE] = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''c:\filename.ext'', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T)
            WHERE REPORT_ID = ...
             '
    exec sp_executesql @dSQL
end try

begin catch
    if @@TRANCOUNT > 0 begin
        rollback tran
        --other instructions for error handling
        --...
    end
end catch

if @@TRANCOUNT > 0  begin
    commit tran
end
```

**The Question**

Is it possible to achieve the desired behavior without using dynamic TSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be best if you just check if the file exists first.

```
DECLARE @isExists INT;
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist 'C:\filename.ext', @isExists OUTPUT

--If the file exists, then 
IF(@isExists = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'It exists!'
    --Do your work here
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --Return some kind of error message
    SELECT 'File does not exist.'
END
```

Comment: Yes, probably this is a better approach, thank you for your answer